# Lie algebra of SU(p,q)?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry

As far as I understand, $SU(p,q)$ are unitary matrices $M$ with $\det M=1$ that preserve a $(p,q)$ form represented by $g=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,\ldots,-1,-1)$ with $p$ positive and $q$ negative entries.

In the vicinity of the identity elements $M\in SU(p,q)$ can be written as exponentials of its algebra:
$$
M = \exp(i\epsilon A)
$$
with $A$ hermitian an traceless. Because $M$ have to preserve $g$, a standard argument leads to
$$
A^\dagger g = g A
$$
or, in other words,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}B & X \\ -X^\dagger & C\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $B\in\mathfrak u(p)$, $C\in\mathfrak u(q)$, $\operatorname{tr}(B) + \operatorname{tr}(C) = 0$ and an arbitrary $p\times q$ matrix $X$. But this $A$ is not hermitian (unless $X=0$, which we cannot have), and so $M=\exp(i\epsilon A)$ not unitary. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is not required that $M$ is unitary? (What is your source?)

Comment: You might be right, I just extrapolated, because I was taught SUSU = Special Unitary. But now I also remember reading that non-compact simple Lie groups don't have finite unitary representations, this would be the confirmation. Thanks!

Comment: Note that unitary matrices are exactly those preserving the form represented by the identity. So when extrapolating from $SU(n)$ to $SU(p,q)$, the unitary condition is replaced by the condition you mention on $g$.